# P5, HTML & CSS - Lining DOM elements inside a grid area

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, p5.js

I am struggling with lining my P5.JS sliders into my CSS grid.
Unfortunately, I don't get this to showcase in the code snippet function. Therefore, I'll paste my code and show the result via an image.

Part of my HTML:

```
  <body>
    
    <div class="menu">
      <h1>MENU</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="outer">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="temp">

        </div>

        <div class="draw">
          <p id="canvas"></p>

        </div>


        <div class="label">

          <label for="shapes">Shapes</label><br>
          <label for="scale">Scale</label><br>
          <label for="rotation">Rotation</label><br>
          <label for="background">Background</label><br>
          <label for="stroke">Stroke</label><br>
          <label for="fill">Fill</label><br>

        </div>

        <div class="slider">

          <p id="shape"> </p>
          <p id="scale"> </p>
          <p id="rotation"> </p>
          <p id="background"> </p>
          <p id="stroke"> </p>
          <p id="fill"> </p>
          <p id="position"> </p>
          <p id="save"> </p>
          <p id="record"> </p>

        </div>

        <div class="check">

          <p id="checkshape"> </p>
          <p id="checkscale"> </p>
          <p id="checkbackground"> </p>
          <p id="checkstroke"> </p>
          <p id="checkfill"> </p>
          <p id="checkposition"> </p>
          <p id="checkpaint"> </p>
          <p id="checkrecord"> </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Part of my CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.outer div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;

}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1vw;
}


.menu,
.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.temp {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.draw {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.label {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  text-align: right;
}

.slider {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}

.check {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;

}
```

Part of my P5.JS (only showcasing some sliders)

```
function setup(){

  canvasForPosition = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  canvasForPosition.parent('#canvas');

  sliderSize = createSlider(10, height,height/2,0.00001);
  sliderSize.parent('#scale');

  checkScaleAuto = createCheckbox('Automate', false);
  checkScaleAuto.parent('#checkscale');


}
```

Outcome:
[image: Outcome of my HTML, CSS, JS]

This is how the lining should look. + I want to add additional labels on the left (The positioning here was made with p5.position):
[image: Demo of the lining]

I was wondering if I could somehow nest another grid into my columns 3/6 and if that is compatible with all browsers. Or maybe there is an option to match the hight of a checkbox with the text and sliders.

Appreciate your help.
Max

Comment: Could you describe what you want the output to look like? e.g. do you want the sliders to be equally spaced vertically in that column.

Comment: Of course. I've added a demo picture. I want the elements in my right grid areas to be aliened on the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of your HTML and the need to have things across the last 3 columns aligned the simplest thing seems to make each a one column, multi row grid. Divide each into say 31 rows of equal size.

You then can place each of the HTML elements exactly in the row you want it to be so that the labels/sliders/checks are aligned as required.

Remove the additional br elements and let the grid do the positioning.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .outer div {
      outline: 1px solid red;
      min-height: 20px;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px;
    }
    
    .outer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 1vw;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 95%;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
      gap: 1vw;
    }
    
    .menu,
    .container div {
      border: 1px solid black;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .temp {
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
    }
    
    .draw {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    }
    
    .label,
    .slider,
    .check {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(31, 1fr);
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      gap: 0.25vw;
    }
    
    .label {
      grid-column: 3 / 4;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .slider {
      grid-column: 4 / 5;
    }
    
    .check {
      grid-column: 5 / 6;
    }
    
    .label>*,
    .slider>*,
    .check>* {
      background: lightblue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="menu">
    <h1>MENU</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="temp">

      </div>

      <div class="draw">
        <p id="canvas"></p>

      </div>


      <div class="label">

        <label for="shapes">Shapes</label>
        <label for="scale">Scale</label>
        <label for="rotation">Rotation</label>
        <label for="background">Background</label>
        <label for="stroke">Stroke</label>
        <label for="fill">Fill</label>

      </div>

      <div class="slider">

        <p id="shape"> </p>
        <p id="scale"> </p>
        <p id="rotation"> </p>
        <p id="background"> </p>
        <p id="stroke"> </p>
        <p id="fill"> </p>
        <p id="position"> </p>
        <p id="save"> </p>
        <p id="record"> </p>

      </div>

      <div class="check">

        <p id="checkshape"> </p>
        <p id="checkscale"> </p>
        <p id="checkbackground"> </p>
        <p id="checkstroke"> </p>
        <p id="checkfill"> </p>
        <p id="checkposition"> </p>
        <p id="checkpaint"> </p>
        <p id="checkrecord"> </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I haven't done any positioning of the labels etc here because I don't know where they are to be aligned to. The 31 rows is a suggestion so you have some to leave as blank space rather than worry about which groups need extra margins as the HTML is not structured that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me a lot in terms of understanding these CSS grids